How can I restrict an app to call GET /applications endpoints to list only applications which is OwnedBy this app
How Can I restrict an app to call GET /applications endpoints to list only applications which is OwnedBy this app?
E.g. I have Masterapp called "prd-masterapp" which is being used to create subapp called "prd-subapp", now If I use prd-masterapp to call GET / applications endpoints this list all the applications in the tenant, I would like to restrict this to list only prd-subapp
Is this possible? Or any reference?
I have checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference - section "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy" but it says with this permission also - it will list all the applications in the tenant.
Is anyone face this kind of challenge? any alternate permission setup? or any alternate solution?

What if you call GET /servicePrincipals/{prd_masterapp_id}/ownedObjects ?

But still GET /applications endpoints list all the application of the tenant - I want to restrict to only list owned applications

I agree with @user2250152, you can make use of below call to list only applications OwnedBy specific app registration.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/spObjId/ownedObjects

I created one app registration with "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy" permission of Application type as below:

Now, I generated one token using client credentials flow and created app registration named "prd-subapp" like this:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
{
"displayName": "prd-subapp"
}


This automatically adds prd-masterapp as owner of  prd-subapp app registration like this:

As mentioned in this MS Document,

The Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy permission allows an app to call
GET /applications and GET /servicePrincipals endpoints to list all
applications and service principals in the tenant. This scope of
access has been allowed for the permission.

When I ran below call with token having  "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy" permission, I too got list of all applications as below:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications

Response:

With "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy" permission, you can list all applications but cannot perform write operations like adding secret, updating  application properties on all applications except on applications OwnedBy that app registration.
To list only applications OwnedBy specific app registration, make use of below API call:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/spObjId/ownedObjects

Response:

